# How to integrate deep linking using branch.io facing issue to create file apple-app-site-association

Tags: ios, xcode8, branch.io

I referenced this link
https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios/ but do not get exact idea for universal link and how to use command

```
cat apple-app-site-association-unsigned | openssl smime -sign -inkey yourdomain.com.key -signer yourdomain.com.cert -certfile digicertintermediate.cert -noattr -nodetach -outform DER > apple-app-site-association
```

Answer (score 1):

To integrate Branch you do not need to use this command. This command was only needed when setting up Universal links on your own to host and sign your own AASA file. Branch will actually will automatically generate and host an AASA file for you. You're better off following [this documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/) to integrate Branch into your iOS app.